# Action/ActionListener method checked even if rendered=false

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, composite-component, jsf-2.2, rendered-attribute

I have a composite component representing a table, that depending on the `editable` attribute (which I have created) may or may not display links to edit a row.

The edit links are of type `<h:commandLink>` and have `actionListener`s pointing to a method in a backing bean. The backing bean for handling editing is provided as a `<cc:attribute name="editBean"... />` like the attribute `editable`, when I want the table to be editable.

If I don't need the table to be editable I set the `editable` attribute to `false` and the links `rendered` attribute gets set to false as well.

My problem is that if I set `editable` to `false` and therefore don't set the attribute `editBean` either, I get errors pointing out that there is no method for handling editing (e.g. java.lang.String does not have the property xxxxx).

I had hoped that as the links are set to not be rendered at all, what has been specified in the action/actionListener would be ignored. To me it feels logical to first check the `rendered` attribute and then, if it's set to `true`, check the other attributes.

So, my questions are: why does it work like this and if there's an elegant way of handling this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSTL `<c:if>` to conditionally build the component in JSF component tree instead of `rendered` attribute to conditionally render the HTML output (it's that you're using JSF 2.2, otherwise I'd have explicitly mentioned that this requires a minimum of Mojarra 2.1.18 to avoid broken view state).

```
<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.editable}">
    <h:commandLink ... />
</c:if>
```